# In Keystone JS v6, is there a way to store users without password being a required option?

Tags: keystonejs, keystone, keystonejs6

I want to offer my users password-based authentication but also the possibility to log in with Oauth providers. I've looked into the Next-Auth adapters to get a reference for creating the schema and I'm also aware that there's an OpenSource package that adapts the `createAuth` method for Oauth, but it seems that the solutions provided force me to pick one of the those two.

I'm not sure how to approach this with Keystone. Should I, for example, create a `Client` list in the form of:

```js
const Client = list({
  fields: {
    name: text({validation: {isRequired: true}}),
    email: text({
      validation: {isRequired: true},
      isIndexed: 'unique',
      isFilterable: true,
    }),
    password: password(),
    oauthProvider: text()
  }
})
```

that represent the clients of my app, and then a `User` for Admins in the form of:

```js
const User = list({
  fields: {
    name: text({validation: {isRequired: true}}),
    email: text({
      validation: {isRequired: true},
      isIndexed: 'unique',
      isFilterable: true,
    }),
    password: password({validation: {isRequired: true}}),
  }
})
```

the latter being the one used as a `listKey` for the `createAuth` function?

I've also thought of generating random passwords for users that Sign In with Oauth, but It feels like a liability from the security standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. You should just be able to set `isRequired: false` for the password field, add whatever other fields you need to store for Oauth then use one or the other.

There's no need to generate random/placeholder passwords; the [Password field](https://keystonejs.com/docs/fields/password) stores bcrypt hashes so blank/missing values will never be matched. Ie. storing `null` in the password field will *prevent* that user from authenticating with a password, it doesn't let people authenticate by submitting a blank string or anything like that.

Does that help?